# Using Lex to count string occurrences, possible problems with makefile

Tags: c, regex, makefile, lex

Currently trying to read a C program using the Lex utility, and display the line occurrences of all the words that aren't reserved C words. I'm running into a huge list of errors saying 'Multiple definition of yyin' 'yyout' 'yylex' 'yy_create_buffer', etc...

I feel like there is a problem with my makefile currently, possibly in my code also.
Any help appreciated!

My Code:

```
#include <string.h>
char currentLines[20][80];
char identifier[1000][80];
void foundWord(char *, int);
int numLine = 1;
%}

%s newStr
%x BLOCK

%%
"/*"                        BEGIN(BLOCK);
<BLOCK>[^*\n]*        
<BLOCK>"*"+[^*/\n]*   
<BLOCK>\n             ++numLine;
<BLOCK>"*"+"/"        BEGIN(INITIAL);

"\n"                              ++numLine;

auto                        ;
break                       ;
case                        ; //full list of reserved words...

[*]?[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*   foundWord(yytext, numLine);
[^a-zA-Z0-9_]+              ;
[0-9]+                      ;
%%

void foundWord(char* newStr, int nLine)
{
char num[10];
sprintf (newStr, "%d", nLine);

int i;
for(i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
{
    if ( strcmp(identifier[i], newStr) == 0 )
    {
        strcat( currentLines[i], ", " );
        strcat( currentLines[i], num );
        return;
    }
}

strcpy( identifier[i], newStr );
strcat( identifier[i], ": " );
strcpy( currentLines[i], num );
}
```

And here is the makefile I have written, attempting to link 'C_words.l' with the lex library.

```
C_words.exe : C_words.o lex.yy.o
    gcc -g -o C_words.exe C_words.o lex.yy.c -ll
lex.yy.o : lex.yy.c
    gcc -g -c lex.yy.c
lex.yy.c : C_words.l
    lex C_words.l
```

This is the input file I would like to use.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int m,n;

printf("Enter the values for  M and N\n");
scanf("%d %d", &m,&n);

if(m == n )
    printf("M and  N are equal\n");
else
    printf("M and N are not equal\n");

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make is smart enough to know how to build C_words.o from C_words.l. So what is happening is your are linking C_words.o ( from C_words.l ) and lex.yy.o ( also from C_words.o ).

Instead of

```
C_words.exe : C_words.o lex.yy.o
    gcc -g -o C_words.exe C_words.o lex.yy.c -ll
lex.yy.o : lex.yy.c
    gcc -g -c lex.yy.c
lex.yy.c : C_words.l
    lex C_words.l
```

Try:

```
C_words.exe : C_words.o 
    gcc -g -o C_words.exe C_words.o  -ll
```

NOTE: If you have a file named C_words.c then C_words.c and C_words.l will collide when building. Rename C_words.c to main.c or something like that. Change the makefile to:

```
C_words.exe : C_words.o main.o
    gcc -g -o C_words.exe C_words.o main.o -ll
```

Comment: That seemed to fix the errors, however the program doesn't seem to do anything, time to look over that

Comment: Put a printf if foundWord() see if it gets that far. I'm not sure what the [*]? is supposed to do in from of the ID rule.

Comment: This: sprintf (yytext, "%d", nLine); is going to wipe out yytext. You need yytext.

Comment: The [*]? is an optional identifier to pick up things like *argv[]. I will update my code to try and fix the yytext

Comment: With updated code I'm hitting this error now.
'expected a ; , or ) before numeric constant' right at the beginning of my foundWord function?

Comment: NAME is probably a macro. Try some other name.

Comment: I've changed NAME to newStr and I still receive the same error, but if I remove the '%s newStr' I don't recieve errors, program just doesn't do anything. I feel like it is because I'm trying to compare it to 0 because it's wondering about the numeric constant, however shouldn't the strcmp allow this?

Comment: Probably what you want is char num[10];
sprintf (num, "%d", nLine);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42002/discussion-between-nicktard-and-charlie-burns)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `-p` option when making?

e.g.

```
C_words.exe : C_words.o lex.yy.o
    gcc -g -p -o C_words.exe C_words.o lex.yy.c -ll
lex.yy.o : lex.yy.c
    gcc -g -p -c lex.yy.c
lex.yy.c : C_words.l
    lex C_words.l
```

Comment: It looks like that took care of the 'Multiple definition of yywrap' however I still recieve the long list of errors.